# Java - Collection to efficiently get interval

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I want to put a lot of objects which have a `public int getTime()` method into a datastructure where I can quickly get a iterable collection with all the objects between a given interval.

For example, I have the following objects and their timestamps:

```
Obj0   00225
Obj1   00236
Obj2   00248
Obj3   00248
Obj4   00253
Obj5   00256
```

Is there a collection where I can efficiently put these objects in, and quickly get an interval as a subcollection? For example: `data.subcollection(00230,00250)` would give me `Obj1`, `Obj2` and `Obj3` in an iterable collection.

Note that there can be two different objects with the same timestamp.

Edit: it would be nice to know which complexity the operations `add()` and `subcollection()` have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TreeMap` could probably do this for you, with a `TreeMap<Integer, ThingWithTime>`.  To get a subrange, query `map.subMap(230, 250).values()` to get the `ThingWithTime` objects with keys in the range 230 inclusive to 250 exclusive.  As usual, you should expect O(log n) complexity.

Comment: But when I have one key for two different objects (in my example `obj2`and `obj3`) I won't get them both in the submap?

Comment: If you have that situation, you might have to do a `TreeMap<Integer, List<ThingWithTime>>` and iterate over the Collection of Lists.

Comment: I just noticed that `size()` won't be accurate when there are two items with the same timestamp.

Comment: Nope, there's no built-in Java solution for that.  You might get somewhere with counting in a separate Guava `TreeMultiset`, but it'd require some work.

Comment: Is it possible to use a `SortedSet` and define how the objects are sorted (and when two items are equal)?

Comment: Not without serious nastiness, not really; I'd pretty strongly advise against that.  (Also, `TreeSet.subSet().size()` is O(n) anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java 8, I suggest you put them in a simple `List` and then use [Parallel Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) for date-based filtering.

Something along these lines:

```
List<Obj> filteredList = objects   // Some form of List with all your objects
                       .parallelStream()
                       .filter(o -> o.timestamp <= high && o.timestamp => low)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I'm using Java 7 and this code is above my level, but I will look into it, thanks!